# Split output from communicate

Tags: python

I am trying to get an output from that program named clasp in a string using communicate but when I try to use split python tells me:

`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`

And when I try to convert the tuple to a string with .join Python says:

`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

So I dont understand the type of output using communicate and I was reading so many post but nothing works. Output is bytes object? or tuple?

```
def resolve(self):
    p = Popen(['clasp', 'propositions.txt'], stdout=PIPE)#stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE 
    output= p.communicate("input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")

    print (output)

    str = '/n'.join(output)
    print (output.split("c Answer: 1",1)[1])
```

Comment: If you don't understand the type of an object you can always output the type of the object via `print(type(output))`. In the case of a tuple it's often helpful to also know the type of the object in the tuple i.e. `print(type(output[0]))`.

Answer (score 2):

first `communicate` returns a `tuple`: output and error data. Do:

```
output, _ = p.communicate("input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
```

then

```
str = '/n'.join(output)
```

makes no sense, `output` is a buffer with all the lines, as `bytes` (and you're not using `str` anyway)

So you just need:

```
print (output.decode().split("c Answer: 1",1)[1])
```

Comment: So with decode now I can save the output in a variable? I mean the text was on bytes and now with decode i convert it in str?

Comment: `decode()` returns a string, yes. You can assign the result of the `split()` operation instead of printing it

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python 3.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) we have

> communicate() returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data). The data will be strings if streams were opened in text mode; otherwise, bytes.

So `output[0]` is the data in stdout so to print that just do `print(output[0])`